# Is there a way to reference a library in Automake?

Tags: automake

I'm trying to use LDADD to reference a prebuilt library and Automake insists that the  library has to be built. The Automake manual says:

"If you need to link against libraries that are not found by configure, you can use LDADD to do so. This variable is used to specify additional objects or libraries to link with; it is inappropriate for specifying specific linker flags, you should use AM_LDFLAGS for this purpose."

In my code I have used both

```
LDADD = ../lib/library.a
```

and

```
prog_LDADD = ../lib/librarya.
```

In both cases make outputs

```
*** No rule to make target 'library.a', needed by 'SlipTest.exe'. Stop.
```

It's got me stumped.
art

Answer (score 0):

check whether the file `../lib/library.a` actually exists.

when building libraries with `automake` you should use `libtool`, and libtool-libraries use the (platform independent) `.la` extension:

```
prog_LDADD = ../lib/library.la
```